# what does @override means? what exactly am I overriding?

Tags: java, android, overriding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When do you use Java’s @Override annotation and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)

I see a lot of @override element in many codes and I don't exactly know what it means.
for example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

I don't know what it means and I don't understand what am I overriding. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 5):

It means you are overriding a method of your parent class (the one you extend from).